# GParted made some of my HDD capacity dissapear!

Tags: dual-boot, windows, gparted

My HDD size was 1TB (dynamic) and there were already 4 partitions in it. One with the Windows C drive (450GB), another recovery (20GB), another with some tools from the laptop manufacturer (about 200MB) and another with my files in it (Drive T: 450GB).

So, I boot the CD, tried installing Ubuntu 13.10 and tried to partition my drive to dual-boot with Windows 7.

When I came to the point to select which partition I should split/create etc, I chose the one with my files (Drive T) and edited the size to about 350GB.

Then an error message came up saying that Parted cannot change dynamic disks and now when I open Windows the 100GB that were supposed to exist as unallocated size do not exist and partition T capacity has dropped to 365GB!!!

As you can see in the [image: screenshot] , weird things happen in Windows, as the drive shows up with two different capacities in the disk management application. (Note: when I open my computer the disk shows up as 365GB)

Has anyone faced a similar problem? What should I do?

Comment: Turn off dynamic partitioning and see what you see.  Linux cannot co-exist with dynamic partitions.

Comment: If (after you disable dynamic partitions), you still dont have all your space, enter gparted, and check each partition. Gparted corrected all the drive capacities when this happened to me.